# Getting a "404 Not Found" when I attempt to "Run Debug Application" of React app in PhpStorm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, debugging, phpstorm

As title says, I'm trying to debug my my React app.

"Run Debug Application" and "Debug Debug Application". Both open up a Chrome window, and it displays the 404.

[image: 404 in Chrome]

[image: Configure Debug]

[image: Debug Settings]

I am running Manjaro Linux.

This has been troublesome. Please accept my apologies; I don't know my way around PhpStorm, so let me know if I've left any information out.

EDIT: I checked the network ports and saw that PhpStorm was already listening on 3000 before I even clicked debug. I cannot run `npm start` for the same reason now.

Killing the process and restarting PhpStorm did nothing, the ports are still being listened on.

[image: Port Listen in terminal]

Thanking you for your time

EDIT: Changing the port number to which the debugger listens had no effect.
[image]

EDIT: Included commands used to start application.[image]

Comment: *"I checked the network ports and saw that PhpStorm was already listening on 3000 before I even clicked debug."* Why did you set the port for Built-in web server to the same 3000? (from your 3rd screenshot). Your `npm start` now cannot start on that port .. since it's **already used** by PhpStorm. Change that port there back to the default (`63342` I believe) and restart the IDE. IDE's built-in simple web server requires project name to be in the URL (e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:63342/PROJECT_NAME/file.html`) and therefore has rather limited usage cases.

Comment: Ah yes, I did that because I used to think that the Debugger was started by clicking the Debug symbol next to the Run button while "npm start" was listed as the run configuration, which caused it to open on port 3000. I thought changing the debugger port to that would fix that and forgot to change it back when I switched to using "Run Debug Application". Editing answer.

Comment: Your new screenshot shows that you are still using built-in web server (`localhost:63342`) while you need to have `localhost:3000` (that's the port is used by `npm start`, right?)

Comment: I was actually running "Debug Application", see edited OP for image.

Comment: You need to change Built-in Server port at File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger to 63342. That's a port used by IDE's built-in Web Server. As you're using `npm start` on port 3000 - you don't need IDE's built-in one, running on 63342. After that change try opening localhost:3000 after npm start again.

Comment: That was suggested by LazyOne; it allows me to run npm-start, but it doesn't fix the original 404 error.

Comment: @JoelNash So what do you have now? What do you do / what URL do you open after doing `npm start`? You should open `localhost:3000` (as this is where `npm start` supposed to serve that site). Show new screenshots of your current configs (all what you are using). **Another way:** close PhpStorm and do whatever you need to so in plain terminal (run `mpn start`, open URL in browser etc) -- does it work / what difference do you see?

Comment: @JoelNash Because if you do all in terminal (when PhpStorm is closed) and it still does not work .. then you must be doing something wrong / sort out that issue first. If it works -- check what you do differently when doing the same in PhpStorm.